# Cloud Firestore API is not enabled, FAILED_PRECONDITION when trying to access from PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to access Cloud Firestore from PHP.  I believe I have everything set up correctly, and it seems to be accepting my authorization file, and gets as far as the snapshot line, but then throws the error "The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project".  I have a separate javascript webpage that accesses this database with no problems whatsoever; trying to build a page for a different purpose that needs to be in PHP, and cannot get past this error.  Any help would be much appreciated...

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=c:/XXX/google-auth.json");
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;
$db = new FirestoreClient();
$docRef = $db->collection('clients')->document('10001');
$snapshot = $docRef->snapshot();
```

Full error message:
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\FailedPreconditionException: { "message": "The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project xxxxx", "code": 9, "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION", "details": [] } in C:\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\GrpcRequestWrapper.php:263 Stack trace: #0 C:\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\GrpcRequestWrapper.php(200): Google\Cloud\Core\GrpcRequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(Google\ApiCore\ApiException)) #1 [internal function]: Google\Cloud\Core\GrpcRequestWrapper->handleStream(Object(Google\ApiCore\ServerStream)) #2 C:\vendor\google\cloud-firestore\src\SnapshotTrait.php(122): Generator->current() #3 C:\vendor\google\cloud-firestore\src\SnapshotTrait.php(61): Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference->getSnapshot(Object(Google\Cloud\Firestore\Connection\Grpc), 'projects/cityda...', Array) #4 C:\vendor\google\cloud-firestore\src\DocumentReference.php(347): Google\Cloud\Firestore\DocumentReference->createSnapshot(Object(Google\Cloud\Fires in C:\vendor\google\cloud-core\src\GrpcRequestWrapper.php on line 263

Comment: This turned out to be a problem with the Authorization file; once I generated one with the correct name, everything worked fine.